# Pull Order Data from AliExpress

Tags: aliexpress, ecommerce

I'm looking to pull purchase details of an order using the order number or other identifying order characteristics (such as phone number) without requiring the end user to login to (or provide authentication details of) his AliExpress account

For example, Walmart allows anyone to access full order details on Walmart.com by providing the order number and phone number associated with the account order was placed from.

Is something like this possible on AliExpress?

Comment: I edited your question ... Does this revision reflects what you actually want to ask?

Comment: @Rubén yes, thank you. I think the question is **much** clearer now. Would this be considered on topic now?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 9 times. Removed [tag:tracking] because the tag usage indicates that it's for use on questions about tools that track user activity like Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

From [How to track my package?](https://service.aliexpress.com/page/knowledge?pageId=37&category=1000022000&knowledge=1060063468&language=en)

> You can also visit [Cainiao](https://global.cainiao.com/?&lang=en) and [17track](https://www.17track.net/en) for more tracking information

I only look at the first one. Apparently it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, as stated in OP, my goal is to obtain order details (including name of item purchased and date/time item was purchased) without having the end user login to his account. Since this solution requires the user to first login to his account it won't solve my problem. On Walmart, one can obtain ALL order details without ever logging in..